# Git Merge not marking up all differences in conflicting text files

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I'm testing out GIT branch merging and conflict resolution with changes to a simple text file.

I've checked-out a branch called `issue1`, made an update to **File_A** and committed the changes.

I've then checked-out `master`, made multiple updates to **File_A** and committed the changes

When I then attempt to `git merge issue1` i get the expected

```
Auto-merging /File_A
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in /File_A
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

however when I open the file the conflict markup only highlights the first difference it finds not any of the others.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-7" ?>
=======
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>>>>>>> issue1
```

Is it possible to easily highlight all the differences in this way or am I going to have to use a different means for conflict resolution?

Comment: Are you sure the changes you made actually conflict? If not, git will automatically merge them. If you want to see a list of all the differences, try `git diff` instead.

Comment: I've just tested some more, I didn't realise git would actually update the file contents as part of the merge without any prompt if it could identify the changes. Is there any way to highlight all file changes when you attempt a git merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some common commands I use.

to get a quick overview

```
git diff -- shortstat master issue1
```

to overview of differences per file

```
git diff --stat master issue1
```

To highlight the differences (not the conflicts) between two commits for a file.  THis will force the ouput to go to the terminal.  See 'git help config'  diff.external section to use an external diff editor.

```
git diff --no-ext-diff master issue1 -- File_A
```

If the files to be merged contain changes but in different parts of the file, they will not show up as conflicts.  The merged (result) file will bring both changes.  It only conflicts if both files want to change the same lines.

Comment: It's the last sentence that I didn't realise and was causing me the headache. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I should have read on before posting the question, this is taken directly from the git merge help file which shows why not all areas of the file had differences highlighted

HOW CONFLICTS ARE PRESENTED
During a merge, the working tree files are updated to reflect the result of the merge. **Among the changes made to the common ancestor’s version, non-overlapping ones (that is, you changed an area of the file while the other side left that area intact, or vice versa) are incorporated in the final result verbatim**. When both sides made changes to the same area, however, Git cannot randomly pick one side over the other, and asks you to resolve it by leaving what both sides did to that area.